# Capturing only relevant records irrespective of whole batch in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table say table A and it has columns as like in below pic1,

CF-458578 is the batch id and CR-12534554 is the entity ID.

Each entity ID is associated with one or more batch id.

CR-12534554 is associated with two batch id namely CF-458578 and CF-459186.

Whenever I find the keyword 'Item removed from' in description field, I want to filter out the only the removed batch and the result should be same like in below pic2,

Note: there is timestamp field in which the description history can be ordered.
[image][image]

Comment: I don't follow the logic.  Nothing in your data is called "batch".  Please try to explain exactly why you are keeping some rows and/or exactly why you are removing others.

Comment: The first four rows in the first pic is related to one batch namely CF-458478(this is batch Id). CF-459186 is another batch id with same entity id CR-12534554. Since CF-459186 is not removed from CR-12534554. The final output should include this particular batch as shown in final pic. Please let me know if stills my question confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, the best solution is probably window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when description like 'Item removed from%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by entityid) as cnt_removals
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_removals = 0;
```

You can also write this as `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.entityid = t.entityid and
                        t2.description like 'Item removed from%'
                 );
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the expected result. Instead it filtered out the whole batch. Please find the expected output in pic2.